# jar file not working with out extracting in other system

Tags: java, jar

I have a build a jar file in java using Command prompt(CMD), the jar file name is test.jar,
First I am using some API's  in my application let it be a.jar and b.jar, I put that file on the same location where my 'test.java' resides. My manifest.text looks as follows:

```
Main-Class: test
Class-Path: a.jar b.jar
```

I have build my jar file using the following command:

```
jar cfm  test.jar manifest.txt test.class a.jar b.jar
```

So I got a jar file, I run that in my machine using the following command:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

It is working perfectly. But when I put this 'test.jar' in another system and run the command it is not working, and when I extract the jar file and and running the jar file run command it works. Why it is not working without extracting in other system? How can I make it work without extracting ? Please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Class-Path: parameter in the manifest to reference jars within the jar you are creating.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html for details.

It works when a.jar and b.jar are in the same directory (which is presumably true where you run it on the original machine) but not on another machine where the only copy is in the jar.

One option is to extract the classes from a.jar and b.jar and jar them up with your test.class.  That will work in most cases.  I believe there are tools that can manage that for you, though I work mostly with Maven projects and just use the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) if I need to combine several jars into one.

Comment: I extracted and tried, but getting error package does not exists

Comment: Show what your directory looks like before jaring it up.  If your test.class isn't in a package and a.jar has files in package com.a, it should look like:
"test.class", "com/a/somefile.class", [etc]